# Scanning tables for information

Tags: tables, data-tables, information

I'm designing a table that shows information for rounds of golf, strokes, points, fairways and so on. The problem is getting the right layout to show this data without crowding the table too much.

The two versions I have come with are as follows.

The first one has the main data in bold and on top of the extra data. "Skor" means strokes, and the main data is for 18 holes and the extra data is for the front/back nine.

[image]

The second has the data all on the same level...
[image]

I know these example are not using the same theme but that is not the point, I'm curious to know which version is the easiest for users to scan for information? I feel like the first one is easier to scan for single rounds, but the second one would be easier if scanning for "strokes" over multiple rounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel that the first table (i.e. main data in bold and on top of secondary data) is a better design because it differentiates between the key information needed by the user and secondary extra information.

By bolding and placing the information in 2 levels, it allows users to quickly scan through the top level (which the bold text will draw the attention of the user) and then focusing on the finer details that interests the user. User eye movement will be smoother, i.e. horizontal and downwards, instead of being interrupted when all the information is on the same level.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I went with a variation of that in the end, much clearer